# Any reason why I cannot grab html text area value using jQuery for modals when using handlebars?

Tags: jquery, mongodb, handlebars.js, bootstrap-modal

```js
// Allow the user to post a note into the db as well as display it in the modal along with all the other notes
$(document).on("click", ".add-note", function() {
  debugger;
  var thisId = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log($(".note-text").val());

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/savednotes/" + thisId,
    data: {
      body: $(".note-text").val()
    }
  }).then(function() { 

  $(".note-text").val("");

  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/savednotes/" + thisId
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data.notes);
    $(".all-notes").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.notes.length; i++) {
      var noteDiv = $("<div>").addClass("added-notes");
      var noteBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn delete-note-btn");
      noteBtn.text("X");
      noteBtn.attr("data-id", data.notes[i]._id);
      $(noteDiv).append(data.notes[i].body);
      $(noteDiv).append(noteBtn);
      $(".all-notes").append(noteDiv);
    }
  });
});
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

    <h3>Saved Articles</h3>

    <div id="articles">
    {{#each savedArticles}}
      <div data-id="{{_id}}" class="article">
      <img class="article-img" src="{{image}}">
      <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank"><h2> {{headline}} </h2></a>
      <p class="byline"> {{byline}} </p>
      <p class="summary"> {{summary}} </p>
      <button data-id="{{_id}}" class="note btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#noteModal-{{_id}}">Add Note</button>
      <a href="/removearticle/{{_id}}"><button data-id="{{_id}}" id="delete" class="btn">Delete from Saved</button></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="noteModal-{{this._id}}" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
                    
        <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h2 class="modal-title">Notes for:</h2>
              <h4 class="modal-title"><i>{{this.headline}}</i></h4>
              <h5>{{this.byline}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

              <form id="form-"{{_id}} class="form-group">
                <div class="all-notes"></div>
                <label for="note">Note:</label>
                <textarea class="note-text form-group form-control" name="userNote" rows="4"></textarea>
              </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button data-id="{{this._id}}" type="button" class="btn add-note">Add Note</button>
            </div>
          </div>
                  
        </div>
      </div>


    {{/each}}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to grab the text area value with jQuery for the first saved article, but I cannot grab it for a second or third saved article. It's grabbing an empty string. I'm using a modal to append the form itself to write a note and the modal works flawlessly for the first article, but when grabbing text for articles that follow nothing is grabbed.

Comment: please provide a working jsfiddle. I guess you mean `$(".note-text").val()` is not working for you because you have more than one .note-text-Nodes and you need to loop through them

Answer (score 0):

Well if I guessed your question right in my comment, here's the solution for you:

```js
 // OUTPUT 1
 $(".note-summary1").val($(".note-text").val()) 
 
 // OUTPUT 2
 var value = "";
 $.each($(".note-text"), function(idx, textArea) {
  value += $(textArea).val();
 });
  $(".note-summary2").val(value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

INPUT:
<textarea class="note-text">Text 1</textarea>
<textarea class="note-text">Text 2</textarea>
<textarea class="note-text">Text 3</textarea>

<br/>
<br/>

OUTPUT 1:
<textarea class="note-summary1"></textarea>
<br/>
OUTPUT 2:
<textarea class="note-summary2"></textarea>
```

The thing is, that `$(".note-text")` returns an array of textareas not just one, so you have to loop through them and get their value. Otherwise `val()` will just return the first value. See the difference between **OUTPUT 1** and **OUTPUT 2**

Comment: @Nicole Carvalho: Please tag the answer if it helped you.